# Generate gif from a Three.Js scene server-side

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, graphics, three.js

I have currently a client-side Javascript code that generates a Gif file from a Three.js scene on the client.

I would like to do exactly the same but on the server-side.
I'm a bit confused about the way to go.

Can I render a scene outside of the browser to generate the Gif?
Should I use node.js implementation of Three.Js? I'm working in a Python environment on the server-side, if possible I'd rather work with something in Python..

Thanks.

Comment: I've tried many things with headless browser (like slimmerjs) but none of them seems to support WebGl which is required by tree.js.

Comment: Does this do what you want? https://github.com/mikolalysenko/headless-gl